# What's the difference between h4 and div if styling can make them look the same?

Tags: css

I'm not a web designer but I faced a situation where I had to make a `div` look exactly as how would a `h4` element look like with our current design as I couldn't control the code producing the `div` elements. I did it but then I wondered what difference is there between `h4` and `div` or any other couple of tags if styling can make them look the same ?

Comment: It's common practice to use `<h*>` tags for SEO. However you can make `div` act like `h4` and there will be no difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics). Think screen readers or webcrawlers (e.g. of searchengines).

It's the same reason (among others) that [new HTML elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#new-elements) are added once in a while.

Answer (score 3):

Semantically, an `h4` represents a 4th level heading, whereas a `div` is just a `div`.

It's about the *meaning* of your data, as opposed to its appearance.

Answer (score 1):

dont do this ,

the seo does make the difference and the The HTML h4 tag is used for specifying level 4 headings. which will be traced/detected by the browser but heading by css wont be recognize as heading by the search engine  so it wont be seo friendly.